# Implementar uma classe CRUD

Tags: php, design-pattern

Tenho uma classe `CRUD` que tem os seguintes métodos:

- ObterConexao()
- Insert($objeto)
- Update($objeto)
- Delete($objeto)
- Select($objeto)

Levando em consideração o `SRP` (Princípio da Responsabilidade Única) que diz:

> Uma classe só deveria ter um único motivo para mudar.

Minha classe `CRUD` **do meu ponto de vista** tem mais que um motivo para mudar, pois se eu precisar alterar a função `Insert`, vou ter que alterar na classe `CRUD`, o mesmo ocorre para as outras funções.

E aí surgiram umas dúvidas:

1 - Segundo o `SRP` minha classe possui mais de um motivo para mudar, estou certo? ou isso não é válido para classes tipo `CRUD`?

2 - Seguindo o `SRP` qual a melhor maneira de se criar uma classe `CRUD`?

3 - Seria ideal ter uma classe para cada operação? ou seria melhor usar interfaces?

4 - No caso de interfaces, como seria feita a implementação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para criar essa estrutura CRUD:

- utiliza interfaces para definir os métodos que suas classes terão que
  implementar.
- crie uma classe abstrata para implementar os métodos;
- crie sua classe CRUD e extenda dessa classe abstrata para já obter
  essas implementações.
- No seu caso, pode sobrescrever o metodos Insert na sua classe CRUD;

exemplo da estrutura:

```
interface ICRUD{
 public function Insert($objeto);
 public function Update($objeto);
 ...
}

abstract class BaseCRUD implements ICRUD{
  public function Update($objeto){
    //implementacao
  }

  public function Insert($objeto){
    //implementacao
  }
}

class Categoria extends BaseCRUD {
  public function Insert($objeto){  //sobrescreve 
    //implementacao personalizada para essa classe
  }
}
class Produto extends BaseCRUD {

}
```

exemplo de uso:

```
$produto = new Produto();
$produto->Insert($objeto);// implementacao feita no BaseCRUD

$categoria = new Categoria();
$categoria->Insert($objeto); //implementacao sobrescrita na class Categoria
```